# BizTalk calling Oracle stored procedure raises System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, biztalk

this was already asked a few times before, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem in other questions yet.

I've generated a BizTalk schema for the stored procedure in Oracle and also set the options for GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyFilePath and GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyKeyPath. I registed the generated Dll in the GAC and specified it's location in UserTypeAssemlyLoadPath.

However, when an orchestration triggers the receive port I get an exception:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_OracleDBBinding_BIZTALK_EULVIS0X" with URL "oracledb://eulvis0x/". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.InvalidOperationException: Benutzerdefiniertes Mapping für 'dataSource='EULVIS0X' schemaName='BIZTALK' typeName='T_LASTPROFILWERT_TABLE'' ist nicht angegeben oder ist ungültig
>
> Server stack trace: 
>          at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".

Translation of German part of the error message

> Custom mapping for 'dataSource =' EULVIS0X 'schemaName =' BIZTALK 'typeName =' T_LASTPROFILWERT_TABLE '' is not specified or is invalid

How can I find out more about the cause of the exception, especiall if there is a problem finding the UDT assembly or if something doesn't fit in the UDT. And if so, what?

Comment: By UDT do you mean User Defined Type?   If so you may want to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788045.aspx

Comment: We've figured out that sometimes the generated assembly simply doesn't work and regenerating it solved the problem.